# как из matrix получить deg?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery, матрицы, transform

У элемента в CSS свойствах установлено `transform: skewX(-5deg);`, а при получении этого свойства в JS `$(element).css('transform')` я получаю `transform: matrix(1, 0, -0.0874887, 1, 0, 0)`. Есть ли какой-то способ, чтоб получить эти самые `-5deg` вместо матрицы?

Comment: asin(-0.0874887) это и будет угол поворота

Comment: @becouse только не арксинус, а арктангенс. Тут не поворот, а наклон

Comment: @AlexeyTen, да, тут арктангенс.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел [статью](https://css-tricks.com/get-value-of-css-rotation-through-javascript/) где описывали функцию получение `rotate()` в `deg` и чуток переделал ее для получения значений `skew()`.

```js
var el = document.getElementById("block");
var st = window.getComputedStyle(el, null);
var tr = st.getPropertyValue("-webkit-transform") ||
   st.getPropertyValue("-moz-transform") ||
   st.getPropertyValue("-ms-transform") ||
   st.getPropertyValue("-o-transform") ||
   st.getPropertyValue("transform") ||
   "FAIL";

console.log('Matrix: ' + tr);

var values = tr.split('(')[1].split(')')[0].split(',');
var a = values[0];
var b = values[1];
var c = values[2];
var d = values[3];
  
var scale = Math.sqrt(a*a + b*b);

var skewX = Math.round(Math.atan(c) * (180/Math.PI));
console.log('skewX: ' + skewX + 'deg');

var skewY = Math.round(Math.asin(b / scale) * (180/Math.PI));
console.log('skewY: ' + skewY + 'deg');
```

```html
<div id="block" style="transform: skew(10deg, 5deg)"></div>
```

Результат работы:

```
INPUT: transform: skew(50deg).
OUTPUT: SkewX: 50deg.

INPUT: transform: skew(50deg, 10deg).
OUTPUT: SkewX: 50deg, SkewY: 10deg.
```